# How to add a sub document model in a collection collection or populate it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I already tried to ask for this question, but i guess i wasn't clear enought since nobody answered, so i am going to give a specific scenario with some code here.

The context is simple, let's imagine a weekly tournament, each tournament is composed by games, which is composed by players.

So we have 3 schemas:

```js
TournamentSchema {
    Games: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' } ]
    Players: [ 
        { 
            _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            points: { type: Number }
        } 
    ] //The total amount of points the user made for this tournament

}

GameSchema {
    Players: [ 
        { 
            _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
            points: { type: Number }
        } 
    ] //The total amount of points the user made for this specific game
}

PlayerSchema {
    pseudo: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    points: { type: Number } // The total amount the player made 
                             // (on every tournaments).
}
```

Everything is fine utill here. 
To not make `find()` et `sort()` by points request every time a client want to display the rank (the `Tournament.Players collection` sorted by points), I keep the Tournament instance into a specific module (so i can just `slice()` the part of the sorted `Players collection` i need to treat).

So everytime a player joins a game, I just have to :

1. Create a new Game instance and add him into it and save it
2. Add him into the existing `Tournament.Players collection` and save it.

The problem is, i can't push a `Model` into the `Tournamanent.Players collection`, I guess mongoose can't manage it (the `Player Model` turns into an `ObjectID` once inserted):

```js
var NewPlayer = new PlayerSchema(
    { pseudo: 'warior', email: 'warioir@something.com' }
);

Tournament.Players.push({ _user: NewPlayer, points: 0 }) 
//add an item: { _user: <ID>, _id: <ID>, points: 0 } pseudo?? email??
```

So when I push a full model Player into the populated Tournament collection of Players, it becomes an ObjectID.

My issue is right here, since after that i have a `Tournament.Players` collection with populated and un-populated Players, it's a pain to manage !
So what i do now is that every time I push a Player Model, i make a new find() with a populate class on the whole Tournament and replace my old instance by the one i just get, but that's a big operation for a very specific need.

How would you manage this situation (need to add a Model on a populated Collection you stored in a module) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in two steps. When a new player joins, create an entry in the User table, get that  _id, then insert that into the Game and Tournament collections. Mongoose isn't as "magical" as other ORMs you may have used in the past. I recently did a 1k line change to remove mongoose from a project and use native drivers instead.